# Oracle: Multi-Column "Closest Match" Autocomplete Strategy

Tags: oracle, autocomplete

I'm implementing an autocomplete that will allow a user to enter in partial text that will then be matched against 4 different columns in a table.  Here is a basic example:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| first_name | last_name | login  | email           |
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| John       | Smith     | jsmith | jsmith@foo.bar  |
| Johnny     | Ringo     | ringo  | ringer@hmm.okay |
| Bob        | Jones     | bjones | j1234@xyz.abc   |
| Jane       | Doe       | doej   | doedoe@blah.umm |
+------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+
```

When the user enters "jo", I want to match the records from this table where at least one of those four columns matches the pattern "jo%".  For this example, only the first two would match due to their `first_name` column values.  If the search were "js", then only the first record would match due to its `login` and `email` column values.  And so on.  I'd also like to return the results ordered by similarity, where the first result is the "closest match", and so on down the results (standard autocomplete behavior).

I've currently been trying to solve this problem using [`UTL_MATCH`](http://pbarut.blogspot.com/2006/12/utlmatch-string-similarity-in-oracle.html), and code that produces the following query:

```
SELECT first_name,
  last_name,
  login,
  email,
      (  utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(first_name, 'js')
       + utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(last_name, 'js')
       + utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(login, 'js')
       + utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(email, 'js')) similarity
FROM users
WHERE LOWER(first_name) LIKE LOWER('js%')
OR LOWER(last_name) LIKE LOWER('js%')
OR LOWER(login) LIKE LOWER('js%')
OR LOWER(email) LIKE LOWER('js%')
ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

The results aren't as accurate as I'd like them to be, and I've seen autocompletes in the wild that work the way I'd like mine to work, but have no idea how they're implemented on the back-end.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you give an example of where the results aren't what you'd want, what you'd rather them be, and why?  My first guess is that you'd want to order the results by the maximum similarity rather than the sum of the similarities of the 4 components and/or that you'd want to weight the fields to match what the user is most likely searching on.  But it's hard to know without more details.

Comment: @JustinCave:  Unfortunately I can't due to a NDA.  But you've brought up some interesting ideas that I hadn't thought about before.  The reason I was using the total was that users can search for multiple terms (e.g. "john sm") and I'm treating each space-delimited word as a distinct search term, applying all the same logic for each.  It's rapidly getting unwieldy, though.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not asking you to post real data, real table structures, etc.  Just an example with the sample data you posted or with a couple more rows of sample data where the sorting isn't what you'd want.  The sample data you posted seems to work reasonably well when you're searching either for 'jo' or 'js' which are the examples you provided so it's hard to see how the question is answerable.  If you can say "I'd rather 'John Smith' sort above 'Bob Jones' when I search for 'jo' because ..." we can likely help.  Otherwise, I think this question is unanswerable.

Comment: why not make some basic rules around the matching (say, where any of the 4 fields begin with the input).  So user enters "j", will return all rows (John, Johnny, Jones, Jane), but for "jo" will only get 3 rows (John, Johnny, Jones).  Simplifies your SQL to just using the like 'jo%' syntax, and is more consistent and understandable imo.

Comment: @tbone:  I'm already doing that in the above query.

Comment: @drrcknlsn yes, i know, i'm just saying stop there, thats good enough.  As you said yourself "It's rapidly getting unwieldly", so why overcomplicate it with jaro-winkler or some other fuzzy logic

Comment: @tbone:  I think it's getting unwieldy because I'm not really that familiar with partial string matching and autocomplete strategies in general.  Simply matching on 'jo%' isn't producing good enough results to be very useful.  We cap the results at the first 10, so if I'm looking for Joe Smith and type "jo" and we use 'jo%' only to match users, then I'm getting back a lot of Johns, Johnsons, Jones, etc. even though Joe is obviously closer to 'jo' than any of those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching is always fun.  You've started a very good basic approach.  What I usually do is create a secondary table loaded via trigger.  The trigger load a primary key from your users table and the second column is the "search" column.  In your example, every row would yield 4 rows.  Make sure you store your results in upper case, so you can index the columns and Oracle will use the index since you are sticking with your like syntax.  It requires an extra table, however the table can be maintained via triggers.

```
    create table searcher
    (
    user_id  number, --FK back to users
    search_column  varchar2(50) -- or whatever size column is appropriate
    );

    select u.first_name, u.last_name, u.login. u.email,
utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(search_column, 'js')
    from users u
    join
    searcher s
    on (u.user_id = s.user_id)
    where s.search_column like upper('js%')
    order by 5;
```

Comment: I think what you're suggesting here is essentially the same as what @JustinCave suggested with respect to using the max similarity of all columns, instead of the total.  The difference being that taking the max in the query doesn't require the separate table.  This method may have a slight performance benefit, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The main difference being my solution will index you query and increase performance.  If you only have 100 rows in your table, it might not matter.  If you have 100,000 then it could be an issue.